# Is it true that sports which use motorized equipment cannot participate in Olympics?

Tags: equipment, olympics, participation

I have heard that sports that use motorized equipment cannot participate in the Olympics, such as [Formula One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One). Is it true or just rumor?

I am talking about those equipments which are used by players while playing.

If this is true, why do they not allow such sports to participate? If it is wrong, is there any sport that uses motorized equipment and has participated in the Olympics?

Comment: Do you mean "motorized" in place of "electronic?"

Comment: @edmastermind29 - Yes. I think "motorized" is more suitable than "electronic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motorsports are not currently part of the Olympics, although there is no rule banning them.  In fact, in the [1900 Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1900_Summer_Olympics) in Paris, automobile, motorcycle, and motorboat racing were demonstration events, and in the [1908 Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_motorsports_at_the_1908_Summer_Olympics) in London, there were three motorboat racing events as an official part of the games.

However, there haven't been any motorsports in the games since then.  IOC president Jacques Rogge, speaking specifically about Formula One, said in 2012,

> Frankly speaking, the concept we are having is the games are about the competition for the athletes not for equipment. Therefore, while having a lot of respect, they will not be included into the Olympic program. ([Source](http://espn.go.com/racing/f1/story/_/id/8140549/ioc-president-jacques-rogge-rules-formula-one-olympic-sport))

As a result, it is not likely that we will see motorsports in the Olympics in the near future, although there are a lot of motorsports drivers and fans that would like to see these events included in the Games once again.